# Ajax error 401 after successful login Laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I have a Laravel 8 project based on auth bootstrap scaffolding.
It uses a custom UserProvider that authenticates a user from another source (AWS user pool). The login process works just fine. However, subsequent Ajax calls to a route fail with error 401. Below are are the details.

**Server side** (config/auth.php)

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'aws',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
]
```

**Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::provider('aws', function ($app, array $config) {
        $awsProvider = new AwsUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
        
        return $awsProvider;
    });
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('ict-devices-table', [IctDataController::class, 'getAllDevices']);
```

**Controllers/IctDataController.php**

```php
class IctDataController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function getAllDevices()
    {
        // return json encoded data.
    }
}
```

**Client side**

As I mentioned, the login is successful, and the user gets redirected to the home page. On that page, the ajax request executes periodically to get the latest data from the 'ict-devices-table' That request returns error 401.

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
    'url': 'http://localhost:8000/ict-devices-table',
    'method': 'GET',
    'contentType': 'application/json',

}).done(function (inData) {
    //do something useful with the data.
});
```

The problem is that the controller never executes if `auth` middleware gets specified in the constructor. If it is not the `getAllDevices` method is called but `Auth::check()` returns false and  `Auth::user()`is null.

However, one clue might be: The custom UserProvider class implements all UserProvider methods, and they get called during login, i.e., `validateCredentials`, `retrieveById,` etc. However, when the Ajax request gets made, none of those calls appear in the log. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?